# Dual monitors for docked laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, thinkpad, dockstation

I'm running Ubuntu on a ThinkPad T14s Gen 2 and using a ThinkPad Universal USB-C docking station. Ubuntu can tell that both monitors are connected and `xrandr` output confirms this. However, I can only turn one on at a time and I can't apply changes in the display settings menu. I tried setting both to 60hz in the display settings as well but even still it will not let me apply the changes. Both monitors are 27 inch LGs connected to the dock by display port and the laptop is shut so built-in display should not be using resources.

I am also able to use both monitors if I plug one directly into my laptop as opposed to both coming from the docking station.

Ubuntu info:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

xrandr output:

```
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3-2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080    144.00 + 120.00   119.88   119.98    99.93    74.99    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024    119.96    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900     119.98  
   1280x960      99.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768     119.93    75.03    60.00  
   800x600      119.93    99.86    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480      119.80    75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-3-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+ 120.00   119.88   119.98    99.93    74.99    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024    119.96    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900     119.98  
   1280x960      99.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768     119.93    75.03    60.00  
   800x600      119.93    99.86    75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480      119.80    75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Settings menu:
[image]